# create processes in visual c++

Tags: c++

i am using visual c++  2010 i  want to learn create processes in c++ can anybody  help where find tutorial or does  here exist book?
thanks

Comment: A quick google should have found you [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425%28VS.85%29.aspx) function very very quickly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below snippet to create process. Just replace the bold part below with the path of the executable which needs to be run.

```
PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo; //we get this as an [out] parameter
STARTUPINFO startupInfo; //this is an [in] parameter
memset(&startupInfo,0, sizeof(startupInfo));
memset(&processInfo,0, sizeof(processInfo));

startupInfo.cb = sizeof startupInfo ;

if (CreateProcess("**Executable_Path**", NULL, NULL,NULL,FALSE,0,NULL,NULL,&startupInfo,&processInfo))
{
   // If process is created successfully

   WaitForSingleObject(processInfo.hProcess,INFINITE);
   CloseHandle(processInfo.hThread);
   CloseHandle(processInfo.hProcess);
}
else
{
   //Cannot create process.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check Win API CrateProcess function:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Please refer MSDN, the best source for Microsoft related technologies.